# How would I go about uninstall my current Nvidia drivers and reinstalling them?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Can I do this easily without borking my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the nvidia driver is just a single package consisting of Xorg drivers and a kernel module which is built during the post installation process.

To remove the default nvidia package, run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

Updated nvidia drivers are available under `nvidia-current-updates`. If you have it installed, uninstall that one as well. Now, you might need to unload the driver. If `sudo rmmod nivida` does not work ("FATAL: Module nvidia is use"), reboot.

Continue by installing the package again:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

At this point, you might need to do another reboot (or re-login) to load the new drivers.